# Ускорение при параллельной реализации программы

Tags: многопоточность, java

Всем дорого времени суток!  
Есть некоторый код, который принимает некоторые параметры и работает с ними, выдавая в конце "качество" работы некоторого алгоритма на этих параметрах. Для подбора наилучших параметров организую проход по координатной сетке, составленной как декартово произведение множеств параметров.

Так вот, если организовать последовательный прогон по, например, 16 значениям точек сетки, то время получается 577 секунд. Если запустить паралельное выполнение на 1 узле кластера (12 ядер - 24 потока с учетом hyperThreading) на 24 потока, то время в одной реализации 122 сек, в другой - 118 сек. Почему параллельное выполнение такое хилое? Ведь, по идее, запуск в 24 потока должен выполняться за время приближенное к 1 проходу, т.е. примерно секунд 40.

Вот одна параллельная реализация (122 сек, Parallel7__Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional - класс имплементит Callable):

```
int processorsNumber = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); // 24 потока
ExecutorService executer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processorsNumber);

List<Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional> tasks = new LinkedList<Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional>();
// в цикле 16 итераций
for ( int i = p_start; i < p_start + n; i++ ){
    for ( int j = i_start; j < i_start + n; j++ ){
        for ( int k = d_start; k < d_end; k++ ){

        double kp = start_kp + (double) step * i;
        double ki = start_ki + (double) step * j;
        double kd = start_kd + (double) step * k;

        tasks.add(new Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional(kp, ki, kd));
        }
    }
}

List<Future<double[]>> res = executer.invokeAll(tasks);

for ( Future<double[]> future : res ){

    double[] results = future.get();

    synchronized (output) {
        output.println(results[0] + "\t" + results[1]  + "\t" + results[2] + "\t" + results[3]);
    }
}
```

И другая параллельная реализация (118 сек, Parallel7__Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional_2 - имплементит Runnable):

```
        ArrayList<Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional_2> tasks = new ArrayList<Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional_2>();

    for ( int i = p_start; i < p_start + n; i++ ){
        for ( int j = i_start; j < i_start + n; j++ ){
            for ( int k = d_start; k < d_end; k++ ){

            double kp = start_kp + (double) step * i;
            double ki = start_ki + (double) step * j;
            double kd = start_kd + (double) step * k;

            tasks.add(new Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional_2(kp, ki, kd));
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        for ( Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional_2 task : tasks ){     
            task.thread.join();
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for ( Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional_2 task : tasks ){

        output.println(task.getKp() + "\t" + task.getKi + "\t" + task.getKd() + "\t" + task.getValue());
    }
```

**UPD**
Засекал время прямо с начала программы. Общее время выполнения, например, первой (долгой) параллельной реализации — 137 сек 
А вот что касается по времени каждого задания (только его время, ничего больше):  
1   125677.0 
2   122276.0  
3   131641.0  
4   112568.0 
5   128192.0 
6   130366.0 
7   130021.0 
8 126856.0 
9   134224.0 
10  131822.0 
11  132999.0 
12  137035.0 
13  120061.0 
14  128839.0 
15  125855.0 
16  115646.0

Вот, что дает запуск последовательной версии программы: 
1   37206 
2   35664 
3   35701 
4   35962 
5   35764 
6   35940 
7   35795 
8   35741 
9   35700 
10 35796 
11  35781 
12  35650 
13 35777 
14 35958 
15 35819 
16 35820 
Общее время — 577 сек.

Почему-то в параллельной реализации задание так долго выполняется... почему так может быть?

Comment: Вы нам расскажите, как каждая задача с памятью работает (чтобы понять, сколько МБ/с ей надо, насколько помогает кэш), выделяется ли/освобождается память динамически, эти 100 млн. объектов - общие или нет, пишут ли в них, есть ли ещё какая-то синхронизация между задачами? Какое время выполнения при 10 потоках?

Comment: Тут вычитал, что Random лучше не использовать в многопоточной программе. Лучше использовать ThreadLocalRandom.
Однако в доках написано:    
>Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the >concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads >may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider >instead using ThreadLocalRandom in multithreaded designs.  
  
В программе у меня все рандомы локальные. 
А тут говорится, что использование одного и того же экземпляра хриново в многопоточной реализации.. Или что-то я путаю?

Comment: а попробуйте использовать оба и посмотреть, как оно будет визуально (в смысле - профайлером).

Comment: >Тут вычитал, что Random лучше не использовать в многопоточной программе. Лучше использовать ThreadLocalRandom



@Stas0n, по-английски именно это и написано - первый Random работать будет, но медленно

Comment: Не понял...    
Там написано, что использование одного экземпляра рэндома в многопоточной программе хриново (concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads)...   
Но у меня то не один рэндом на всю программу - несколько.. все они локальные..

Comment: Да, но "Consider instead using ThreadLocalRandom in multithreaded designs", что в переводе означает "подумайте над использованием класса ThreadLocalRandom в многопоточных программах, с ним у вас всё будет хорошо"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я могу ошибаться, но насколько я помню hyper threading не даёт двухкратный прирост тактов процессора. Настоящее и виртуальное ядро используют один набор конвееров. Второе, виртуальное ядро, вступает в дело тогда, когда первое ядро ждёт данных из памяти. Так что некорректно считать что у вас 24 ядра. У вас их 12. И 12 кэшей. В которые вы пытаетесь впихнуть 24 треда и они дерутся за проц. Ещё один возможный вариант - вымывание кэшей из-за постоянного переключение и постоянные cache miss-ы..

В общем первым шагом я бы попробовал позапускать с разным кол-вом тредов, от 12 до 48 и выбрать наилучший вариант.

Второй шаг - попробовать улучшить локальность данных, уменьшить их объём, проверить что вы матрицы обходите по строками а не по столбцам, не юзаете линкед листы и т.д. Ну и вообще попытаться влезть в размер кэша процессора если это возможно.

В третьих я бы проверил были ли у вас GC и как там вообще дела с памятью обстоят.

Comment: Прогон на разных количествах тредов уже сделал. Победили 10 потоков.
Что касается данных... Вообще говоря, там есть считывание файлов ресурсов (десериализация xml). И это делается для каждого таска, т.е. для потока. Да, затратно - это в первую очередь хочу убрать: один раз считать все, что нужно с ресурсов, а дальше передавать это потокам.

Comment: Знаю пару мест, где можно оптимизировать сам код, который на вход принимает набор параметров...
То, что есть ускорение при переходе от arrayList к массиву — это так (учитывая сколько объектов хранится в списках)
А что касается памяти? Есть ли разница в используемой памяти для списка из 100 млн объектов или массива из тех же объектов?

Comment: ArrayList внутри содержит тот же массив, разницы большой быть не должно. Выкладывайте что-ли код. Пооптимизируем :)
100 млн объектов в хипе звучит очень подозрительно. Они же все лежат в разных концах памяти. Итерация по ним - один сплощной и беспрерывный cache miss. В общем выкладывайте весь код, если он не секретный конечно.

Comment: Да нет, какой там секрет) Дело в том, что кода реально много и это уже, как говорится, "совсем другая история"...    
Что касается оптимизации, то есть один момент: создается список(нефикс. размера) и дальше в него кладутся элементы. Это неправильно с точки зрения того, что перевыделение размера идет..

Comment: Аммортизированная сложность вставки в ArrayList константная, даже с учётом переаллокаций. Я не думаю что в это проблема. У вас время работы всей программы около 2-х минут, врядли заполнение начального листа занимает существенную часть от этого. ИМХО проблема в алгоритмической сложности вычислений и(или) в организации данных в памяти. Ставлю на второе, т.к. 100 лямов объектов это много.  Для начала можно попробовать профайлер http://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/. Если его ещё ни разу не прогоняли, скорее всего 1-2 узких места он вам найдёт. А потом уже и код можно смотреть и думать дальше :)

Comment: Благодарю, займусь!

Answer (score 2):

Вы увидели действие закона [Амдала](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0).

Comment: Я тоже так сначала подумал, но потом небольшая прикидка меня переубедила. Так, если рассматривать самый длинный фрагмент (это прогон алгоритма на наборе параметров), то время должно быть ограничено снизу где-то 577/16 =~ 40 секундами.    
Почему же тогда общее ускорение в 3 раза больше? Я понимаю, если бы было 50-60 секунд, но 120...?

Comment: потому что Вы пренебрегаете накладными расходами. Думаете создание потока - это операция, которая выполняется за 0 секунд?  Вполне может оказаться, что создание нового потока (несмотря на тредпул) по скорости сравнимо с длительностью выполнения тела потока. А тут Амадал и выступает во всей красе.

Comment: Я не пренебрегаю этими расходами...    
1 прогон программы на одном наборе параметром - 35 секунд. Неужели создание 2 потоков сведет время выполнения не до 40 секунд, а до 120?

Comment: да, такое может быть. Например из за того, что данные "перекрываются" и процессор постоянно сбрасывает кеш. Или неявные блокировки.

Но на подобное я с java уже один раз натыкался. Когда обычная программа суммирования ряда чисел на java работала в полтора раза быстрее, чем на чистом С. А там один for! Но потом оказалось, что заботливая java распараллелила цикл. Вполне возможно, что в Вашей якобы однопоточной версии на самом то деле работает несколько потоков.

Comment: Java может от своей "заботы" где-то втихаря распараллелить, например, цикл?

Comment: я такое как раз и видел. Это очень хорошо объясняет все наблюдаемое. Где то я встречал ключик, который запрещает использовать несколько потоков.

Comment: а я вот искал что-то подобное.. не нашел ничего(  Можно где-то про этот ключ почитать?     
    
Я вот знаю пару мест, где можно оптимизировать сам код, который на вход принимает набор параметров...
То, что есть ускорение при переходе от arrayList к массиву — это так (учитывая сколько объектов хранится в списках)
А что касается памяти? что больше есть список из 100 млн объектов или массив из тех же объектов?

Comment: Java сама что-то не параллелит? Пруф или не было :)

Comment: ссылка на [статью](http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2012/07/23/is-cc-worth-it/). Когда мне первый раз показали и я у себя на машине потестил, я был малось в шоке, как java на таком простом обгоняет. Но если потестить на одноядерной машине, то все стает на свои места - java отставала в раза полтора (что ожидаемо и нормально). Я не большой спец в настройке jvm, но знакомый добавил ключик, который по его словам разрешал использовать только одно ядро и тесты снова стали адекватными. Так как в том примере для GC нет особой работы, то только распаралеливание.

Comment: Мифология какая-то и предположения. После того, как отработает JIT, такой примитивный код, как по ссылке скомпилируется в тот же нативный код, что и на с++. Разница косметическая и скорее происходит из-за того насколько хорошо поработал компилятор. Компиляция плюсов с оптимизацией обгоняет Java. "GCC 4.7 (with -funroll-loops) 2000" Если бы там был мультитрединг разница было бы в разы.